# Which member do I put my code in?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I'm writing my first SIMPLE DB app, basically, an offline db, select a listing of records, and then, click on one of those to display on the detail.

I looked at an older book for an example (pre xcode 4) because it had an example very similar to what I needed to do. So the example set up all the methods I'd need to access the database in a member called DBAccess.m  AND I can tell from the debugger that the code visits main.m and then MasterViewController.m it executes awakeFromNib and didViewLoad  which is awesome... BUT where do I put my first statement that calls the routine I need that's in my DBAccess.m file?  The book assumes you KNOW where to put your code and leaves it as an exercise for the user... ugh.

I can't find any definitive statement about how you insert your code into the execution cycle.

Is there a default execution cycle?

Answer (score 0):

The two classic places to put code are in the init and the loadView methods of the view controller. Ie

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if (self) {

    // Put DB code here

  }
  return self;
}
```

Or

```
- (void)loadView
{
  [super loadView];

  // Put DB code here

}
```

The choice will depend on what you are doing with the data.

If the data is going to be displayed  in UI elements from a NIB file, then you have to be a little careful as those elements are not likely to exist yet when the `init` method runs.  Thus assigning DB data to UI elements in `init`  can result in a program that looks right and compiles, but does not display any thing on the display (Been there, done that!)  Thus you are better off delaying the DB data  until the `loadView` fires.

If the data is not needed onscreen immediately (or is required for other non-display reasons) then you can load it in the `init` method.  But the caveat there is that you are now consuming memory for things that may never be displayed - thus defeating any lazy loading during the `loadView` method.

But it all comes down person preference.

Comment: Peter,  thanks for your help.  I didn't realize I'd forgotten to indicate how helpful it was. I have done so now and apologize for the delay.  Thank you very much for your help!